# adding textview dynamically without results

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog

I'd like to show an activity as a dialog but this dialog will show a layout which is filled in dynamically from a database but I am getting no results.

```
package chintan.khetiya.sqlite.cursor;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class lista extends Activity {

    private ListView lista; 
    DatabaseHandler db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listado);

        //SE HACE TODO EL PROCESO EJECUTANDO UNA FUNCION

        Refresh();

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position,long id) {

                       final int selected_row = position;

                       final String cliente = DameCliente(selected_row);
                       final int limite = DameConteo();
                       int i;

                       AlertDialog.Builder myDialog 
                       = new AlertDialog.Builder(lista.this);
```

My problem is here

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.generar_text);
TextView text = new TextView(lista.this);
text.setText("hola");
```

Of course this is a test. I'll do a loop to create many more textviews but I need to build the first one and then loop more.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
myDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null));
myDialog.setTitle(cliente);
myDialog.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    // do something when the button is clicked
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    }
});
myDialog.setNeutralButton("Eliminar Pedido", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    // do something when the button is clicked
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        final int eliminar = selected_row + 1;
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogoDentro = new AlertDialog.Builder(lista.this);
        dialogoDentro.setTitle("Alerta !");
        dialogoDentro.setMessage("Eliminar el Pedido ?");
        dialogoDentro.setNeutralButton("Eliminar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener( {
             // do something when the button is clicked
             public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                 db.Delete_Pedido(eliminar);
                 lista.this.Refresh();
             }
        });
        dialogoDentro.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // do something when the button is clicked
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            }
        });
        dialogoDentro.show();
    }
});
myDialog.show();
}
});
}

public void Refresh(){
    int limite = DameConteo();// numero de columnas insertadas como productos
    int numero_pedidos = NumeroPedidos();



        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Valor Columna: " + ValorColumna(columna) + " -- Columna: " + columna + " -- Precio : " + ValorPrecio(columna), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ArrayList<lista_entrada> datos = new ArrayList<lista_entrada>();  

        for (int a = 1; a <= numero_pedidos;a ++){

            String pedidor = InfoPedidos(a).getString(1);
            float iva = (float) 1.16;
            int articulos = 0;
            float subtotal = 0;
            float total = 0;

                for (int b=0; b<limite; b++){
                String columna = DameColumna(b).toString();
                articulos = articulos + ValorColumna(columna,a);
                subtotal = subtotal +  (ValorColumna(columna,a)*(ValorPrecio(columna)));
                total = total + (float) (((ValorColumna(columna,a)*(ValorPrecio(columna)))) * iva);
                }

                datos.add(new lista_entrada(pedidor,"Pedido: " + articulos + " artículos", "Subtotal: $" + String.format("%.2f", subtotal), "Total: $" + String.format("%.2f", total)));
                //}
        }

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_listado);
        lista.setAdapter(new lista_adaptador(this, R.layout.entrada, datos){
            @Override
            public void onEntrada(Object entrada, View view) {
                if (entrada != null) {
                    TextView nombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nombre); 
                    if (nombre != null) 
                        nombre.setText(((lista_entrada) entrada).getNombre()); 

                    TextView articulos = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.articulos); 
                    if (articulos != null)
                        articulos.setText(((lista_entrada) entrada).getArticulos()); 

                    TextView subtotal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subtotal); 
                    if (subtotal != null)
                        subtotal.setText(((lista_entrada) entrada).getSubtotal());

                    TextView total = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total); 
                    if (total != null)
                        total.setText(((lista_entrada) entrada).getTotal());
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Refresh();

        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) { 
            case R.id.Clientes:
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Main_Screen.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.Productos:
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Product_Screen.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.Nuevo_Pedido:
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, home_screen.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.listado_pedidos:
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, lista.class));
                return true;    

            case R.id.salir:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }

 public String DameCliente(int contact_name){

        //product_data.clear();
    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        ArrayList<Pedido> pedido_array_from_db = db.Get_Pedido();

        String cte_name = pedido_array_from_db.get(contact_name).get_contact_name();
        return cte_name;
    }

 public int DameConteo(){

     db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
     int conteo = db.Get_Total_Products();
     return conteo;
 }

 public int NumeroPedidos(){

     db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
     int numero = db.Get_Total_Pedido();
     return numero;
 }

 public Cursor InfoPedidos(int id){

     db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
     Cursor cursor = db.Get_Pedido(id);
     return cursor;

 }

 public String DameColumna(int columna_id){
     db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
     ArrayList<Columna> columna_array_from_db = db.Get_Columna();

     String columna = columna_array_from_db.get(columna_id).get_columnaName();
     return columna;

 }

 public int ValorColumna(String columna, int a){
     String valor_a = String.valueOf(a);
     db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
     int valor = db.get_valor_columna(columna,valor_a);
     return valor;

 }

 public float ValorPrecio(String columna){
     db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
     float valor = db.get_valor_precio(columna);
     return valor;

 }


}
```

Comment: the "linear" layout is part of the R.layout.dialog, is it? What I mean is the linearlayout and the textview where you face the problem are the elements of the dialog..is that right?

Comment: it's right, the problem is in the dialog. I have no errors but neither  can watch results.. the content of the dialog is empty.

Comment: YES, the "linear layout" is part of the R.layout.dialog, it has no TextView within. I need to dinamically build it in the .java file.

Comment: I have put up a answer based on your comment.Check it out. Should work..lemme know if you face any issues

Comment: This is not directly related to your problem, but have you considered using a ListView with a TextView as the item of the ListView? ListView may solve a lot of UI problems for you and also in case you will end up with a lot of data from the DB it will save you from memory problems, as well. Since the ListView reuses the UI views instead creating n views thus require far less memory than creating and adding n TextViews.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Change

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.generar_text);
TextView text = new TextView(lista.this);
text.setText("hola");
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
myDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null));
```

to

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.generar_text);

TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setText("hola");
linear.addView(text);
myDialog.setView(view);
```

Comment: i already have this, adding my string "text".
If I use your code it crashes.

Comment: Did you replace the relevant code with the code I posted? What does the logcat say?

Comment: **these are the errors...**

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at chintan.khetiya.sqlite.cursor.lista$1.onItemClick(lista.java:61)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298).

**and to many more, when i change the code with your last post.**

Comment: My wild guess is that there is no LinearLayout with id R.id.generar_text in the dialog layout. Also note: you have to define the width and the height of the TextView !!! Just as you need to define it when you are defining the TextView in a XML layout definition

Comment: @bigmerol Why do you have the class and listview with the same name 'lista'? Name them differently and when you use the context in the textview use the activity context

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.generar_text);
TextView text = new TextView(lista.this);
text.setText("hola");
```

to:

```
AlertDialog dialog=myDialog.create();
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.generar_text);
TextView text = new TextView(lista.this);
text.setText("hola");
dialog.show();
```

Comment: when i do that, eclipse make me follow some steps to correct an error at the end send me another error...

LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) myDialog).findViewById(R.id.generar_text);

**ERROR**

Cannot cast from AlertDialog.Builder to Activity. @vipul mittal

Comment: your myDialog is object of AlertDialog.Builder you need to first call create on it and then call findViewById

Comment: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content @ vipul mittal.

**Crashes Again**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically add Views to a ViewGroup (for example LinearLayout) the easiest thing you can do is to define the View (for example TextView) in a separate layout xml file.

for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:id="@id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
 />
```

stored as ***/res/layout/mytextview.xml***

Now in code where you want to put the Views dynamically instead of finding one by findViewById you inflate each time a new instance of the view for example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rootView);

for( int i=0; i < 5; ++i )
{
     TextView mytextview = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview, null);
     mytextview.setText("hola");
     rootView.addView(mytextview);
}
```

Note: if you do it this way you can set all the styling and stuff in the XML for the View you want to add dynamically multiple times. This can save you from a lot of writing since defining the look of a View in code involves a lot more "writing" than it is required in XML.

Comment: it works perfectly out of myDialog, but i need to do in myDialog. Maybe i don't know how to implement it but at the moment can't use that. @ Marek Szanyi

Comment: Ah I know what you are missing ! You have to set the content view of the dialog to your custom layout. So in your case that would be dialogoDentro.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);